# Custom Options config

Tags: custom-options

I'm trying to assist my developer team.

I'm the client :-)

We're trying to replicate this (non-Magento site) pricing display.

https://www.broadcastwarehouse.com/aea-technology/140-525-antenna-analyzer-/349/product

and now on my Magento CE 1.9 site default product (ticked) and optional product below.

http://www.transmittersrus.com/aea-140-525-analyzer-5006-5001/

Both prices are added into Custom Options field in admin.
As one has to have something in the pricing field under simple product I have 0.00. Any other price and it just adds to whatever you have in Custom Options. This is driving us crazy.

Have a play with the BW products and see how the main price box changes and would really like to know if this can in some way be replicated in Magento. I don't mind a third party plug-in but would prefer to try and stay within 1.9 if at all possible.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

David

Comment: Optimally, add a screenshot of the wished behaviour so that it is still understandable even if the link does not work any more.

Comment: Hello Simon,  By simply playing with the two products on the BW site sink you can see exactly what I'd like to do and what should be displayed in the price box. My site's link is of exactly the same product with optional product. I'm happy to add screenshots if you wish but not sure they will tell you any more?

Comment: I know. But this site may be offline some day, so that it is best practice to not only post a link, but a screenshot with the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Custom Options in Simple product, You should use Bundle Product for it. It will work exactly the way you want.

The Main advantage of using Bundle product will be, You inventory will be managed properly for all items.

You can learn about bundle from from [Magento Bundle Product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product)

Comment: Hi Dexter, But this is not a bundled product as such but a product in it's own right as supplied by the manufacturer. It is not myself, the reseller that is adding one or more products to a default product. This particular product is the main product, the Antenna Analyzer in this case while the optional product is the same unit but with a protective travel case. As this is an optional product I would prefer to treat it as such rather than create a separate product page which would be another way round this problem. Also, a Bundled product is not correct as you would end up with two analyzers.

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to say? aren't `140-525 Analyzer 5006-5001`  and `140-525 Analyzer Kit 5006-1500` separate products in ref website?

Comment: Hi Dexter, They are indeed separate products however the only difference is that in the second option you are adding a travel case to the first option. The second option is therefore 1 x Analyzer & 1 x Case and is titled by the factory (my supplier) Analyzer Kit and as you see with it's unique order number. If you still think this can be configured as a bundle then I will suggest this to my developer. Just to get this strait and so I fully understand are you suggesting just configuring the second option as a bundled product? I think we're still going to have issues with correct price display.

Comment: How can I add screenshots as I should like to show you my admin config?